# Find first Monday from date (and every consecutive Monday) and include the first day of every month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So if the source date is `2022-10-27` (existing as the last row in `Table[Field])` then I need a formula to populate a table like the below

```
2022-10-31
2022-11-01
2022-11-07
2022-11-14
2022-11-21
2022-11-28
2022-12-01
2022-12-05
2022-12-12
...
```

How can I make this table?

I've managed to find the next Monday using `=INDEX(Table[Field],ROWS(Table[Field]))+(7-WEEKDAY(INDEX(Table[Field],ROWS(Table[Field])),2)+1)`.This formula exists in D2 and dynamically updates depending on the last row in `Table[Field]`, which works well.

And I find every consecutive Monday thereafter by using `=D2+(7-WEEKDAY(D2,2)+1)`, this is dragged down to populate another table.

But I am getting stuck trying to include the first of every month in here too.

[Here is a sample of what the resultant table looks like (without the first of the month added)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oQre.jpg)

Comment: How about creating two columns of data, one with your Mondays and one with the first day of the month, then merge and sort them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If '27-10-2022' is the start try:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=MIN(EOMONTH(A1,0)+1,A1+(7-WEEKDAY(A1,2)+1))
```

Is this what you are trying?

Comment: Bru...! cracking job my good sir!